# vue transition-group appear event not being called

Tags: vuejs2, transition

I am trying to hook into the appear event lifecycle and call a method in the component but the method getCalled() in my component is never called upon. The transition animation for after-leave event works as intended its just the appear events that do not.

according the documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#transition I can hook into the appear event system as demonstrated.

```
<transition-group name="order" tag="div" appear v-on:after-leave="activateScrollToBottom" v-on:after-appear="getCalled" v-on:before-appear="getCalled" v-on:appear="getCalled">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation and found out that I was missing the `done` callback in the `appear` method.

I put together a very simple CodePen to see, if it is actually working
https://codepen.io/rowild/pen/LJvEKm

JavaScript:

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods:{
    // Transition hooks
    beforeAppear(el){
      console.log('  BEFORE APPEAR')
    },
    appear(el, done){
      console.log('  APPEAR')
    },
    afterAppear(el){
      console.log('  AFTER APPEAR')
    }
  }
},
// Lifecycle hooks
beforeCreate(){
  console.log("BEFORE CREATE")
},
[...]
```

Template

```
<div id='app'>
  <transition
    appear
    @before-appear="beforeAppear"
    @appear="appear"
    @after-appear="afterAppear"
    @appear-cancelled="appearCancelled"
    :css="false"
  >
  <p>TEST CONTENT</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Console output

```
BEFORE CREATE
CREATED
BEFORE MOUNT
  BEFORE APPEAR
  APPEAR
  AFTER APPEAR
MOUNTED
```

In case you found, what your problem was, would you mind to post an explanation and how you solved it? Thank you!